# Reverse Characters in Each Individual Word in String Preserving Whitespace

Tags: java

I have a String which reads as follows:

```
String sentence = "Book on the table but not over there \n" + 
                  "Almost there\r" +
                  "Have fun!"
```

I want the output to be

```
                  "kooB no eht elbat tub ton revo ereht \n" +
                  "tsomlA ereht\r"+
                  "evaH !nuf"
```

But using the code below outputs

```
                 "kooB no eht elbat tub tno revo ehtre \n" +
                 "tsomlA ehtre\r"+
                 "evaH !nuf"
```

How do I accomplish the desired output?

Note: There is a space at the end of first line.

```
private static String reverseWords(String sentence) {
    HashMap<String, String> wordChain = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(sentence));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
                String word = words[i];
                wordChain.put(word, reverseCharacters(word));
            }
            for(String key: wordChain.keySet()){
                sentence = sentence.replace(key, wordChain.get(key));
            }

        }

    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sentence;
}

public static String reverseCharacters(String word){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = word.length()-1; i >=0; i--){
        sb.append(word.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you don't really have to re-invent the reverse logic:

```
public static String reverseCharacters(String word){
    return new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();
}
```

Edited: [Complete code](https://ideone.com/SPtnFi) that preserves whitespace.

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final String sentence = "Book on the table but not over there \nAlmost there\rHave fun!";
        System.out.println(sentence);
        final char[]letters=sentence.toCharArray();
        final StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder();
        final StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
        for(char c:letters)
        {
            if(Character.isWhitespace(c))
            {
                reversed.append(tmp.reverse()).append(c);
                if(0 < tmp.length())
                {
                    tmp.delete(0,tmp.length());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tmp.append(c);
            }
        }
        if(0 < tmp.length())
        {
            reversed.append(tmp.reverse());
        }
        System.out.println(reversed);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'd like to preserve whitespace as I mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

When you reverse `no` you will get `on` - and if you replace `no` to `on`, your `on` in **`ton`** also gets replaced too, resulting **`tno`**. After when you check for `ton` it doesn't exists, but you expected `ton` to be replaced by `not`, so it can't.

Try appending reversed words as you reverse, like:

```
private static String reverseWords(String sentence) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(sentence));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
                String word = words[i];
                sb.append(reverseCharacters(word));
                if (i < words.length - 1) {
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
            }
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String str = sb.toString();
    return str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: How about "ehtre" ? What not "ereht"?

Comment: @user7755336 All `the` gets replaced by `eht` - resulting `there` to become `ehtre`.

Comment: Can we accomplish this without hardcoding "\n"? This can't handle the situation when there is no newline or other linefeed ("\r") at the end.

Comment: @user7755336 Edited.

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a space (" ") before line separator

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are replacing words without considering whitespaces.
For example `wordChain` has on->no and not->ton. So when replacing, 'not'->'ton'->'tno'.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `sentence = sentence.replace(key, wordChain.get(key));`. First you have `there`, then you replace the word `the` with `eht`, now your word `there` becomes `ehtre`.

The most simple way is to concat every reversed word to a new sentence.

```
static String reverseWords(String sentence) {
    StringBuilder newSentence = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(sentence));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            newSentence.append(reverseCharacters(words[0]));
            for(int i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
                String reversed = reverseCharacters(words[i]);
                newSentence.append(" ").append(reversed);
            }
            newSentence.append("\n");
        }
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!sentence.endsWith("\n"))
        newSentence.deleteCharAt(newSentence.length() - 1);
    return newSentence.toString();
}
```

Comment: @zhn Can we accomplish this without hardcoding "\n"? This can't handle the situation when there is no newline or other line feed "\r" at the end.

Comment: You can check if ```sentence``` is end with ```\n```. If it is not, delete the last char in ```newSentence```.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you please implement in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with zhh,for the reason
`String.replace()`
will replace all the word in your sentence,so you may see "there" also include "the",so here you came across problem only on "there"=>"ehtre"

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code to get the desired output. This happens in three steps:

1. Creates non-whitespace character strings (words) and whitespace
   character strings (whitespace words) and stores them in respective
   `List<String>` collections.
2. The words in the character strings are reversed (e.g., Book -> kooB).
3. Assemble the reversed words and the whitespace words to get the result.
4. Optionally, verifies the whitespaces are preserved.

NOTE: The whitespace is as defined at [Character.isWhitespace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReverseTextTest {

    private static String sentence =
        "Book on the table but not over there \n" + 
        "Almost there\r" +
        "Have fun!";                    
    private static List<String> whitespaceWords = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        // Build words and store whitespaces
        List<String> words = getWords();
        System.out.println(words);
        // Build the reversed words
        List<String> wordsReversed = getReversedWords(words);
        System.out.println(wordsReversed);
        // Assemble reversed words and the whitespaces
        String result = assembleWordsAndWhitespaces(wordsReversed);
        System.out.println(result);
        // Verification
        printToVerify(result);
    }

    /*
     * Accepts input string of words containing character words and
     * whitespace(s) (as defined in the method Character#isWhitespce method).
     * Processes and returns only the character strings. And, stores the
     * whitespace 'words' (a single or multiple whitespaces) in a List<String>.
     * NOTE: This method uses String concatenation in a loop. For processing
     * larger inputs consider using a StringBuilder.
     * NOTE: The whitespace is as defined in the Character.isWhitespace()
     * https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html.
     */
    private static List<String> getWords()
            throws IOException {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        String word = "";
        String whitespaceWord = "";
        boolean wordFlag = true;
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(sentence);
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            char c = (char) reader.read();
            if (! Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                if (! wordFlag) {
                    wordFlag = true;
                    whitespaceWords.add(whitespaceWord);
                    word = whitespaceWord = "";
                }
                word = word + String.valueOf(c);
            }   
            else {
                if (wordFlag) {
                    wordFlag = false;
                    words.add(word);
                    word = whitespaceWord = "";
                }
                whitespaceWord = whitespaceWord + String.valueOf(c);
            }
        } // end-for
        reader.close();
        if (! whitespaceWord.isEmpty()) {
            whitespaceWords.add(whitespaceWord);
        }
        if (! word.isEmpty()) {
            words.add(word);
        }
        return words;
    }

    private static List<String> getReversedWords(List<String> words) {
        words.replaceAll(word -> getReversedWord(word)); // can also use a for-loop
        return words;
    }   

    private static String getReversedWord(String word) {
        StringBuilder sbWord = new StringBuilder(word);
        return sbWord.reverse().toString();
    }

    private static String assembleWordsAndWhitespaces(List<String> wordsReversed) {
        String resultString = "";
        char firstChar = sentence.charAt(0);
        if (Character.isWhitespace(firstChar)) {
            // The text start with whitespace
            for (int i = 0; i < whitespaceWords.size(); i++) {
                resultString = resultString.concat(whitespaceWords.get(i));
                if (i < wordsReversed.size()) {
                    resultString = resultString.concat(wordsReversed.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // The text start with alpha word
            for (int i = 0; i < wordsReversed.size(); i++) {
                resultString = resultString.concat(wordsReversed.get(i));
                if (i < whitespaceWords.size()) {
                    resultString = resultString.concat(whitespaceWords.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        return resultString;
    }

    // This is to verify that the whitespaces are substituted correctly.
    // This prints with "\n" and "\r" literals substituted 
    // for \n (linefeed) and \r (carriage return) respectively.
    // For example: "abc \n xyz" will print literally as: abc \n xyz
    private static void printToVerify(String result) {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            char c = result.charAt(i);
            if (c == ("\r".charAt(0))) {
                System.out.print("\\r");
            }
            else if (c == ("\n".charAt(0))) {
                System.out.print("\\n");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```